# Drive Warning: /dev/hda3 (/usr) is 87% full

Tags: linux, centos

As the title stated, I'm getting a drive warning via email from my server.  I was told to use the following command to determine where the disk space usage is coming from.  Is it possible for me to sort the results based on disk usage?  It returns a long list that is hard to sort through...

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /usr
```

**Update:**

What kind of data is stored here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
du --max-depth=2 /usr | sort -n | less
```

sorts the output and less allows to scroll up again

Comment: Also the `-b` option to du will give you bytes used.

Comment: Add the "-h" option to get human readable in MegaBytes

Comment: can `sort` handle the abbreviations?

Comment: No. If you're passing it into sort, then don't use -h. Use -b, -k or -m.

Comment: That just outputs blank lines...